# Why Am I Getting A NoMethodError for a defined method?

Tags: ruby

When I try to run this script, I get a `NoMethodError` for the `getGames` method despite having defined the method and requiring the file in which it is defined.

index.rb

```
require './steam.rb'

getGames()
```

steam.rb

```
def getGames()
  currentID = 0
  while currentID < 100 # !!TODO!! Change to Production Value

    # Get JSON of Game
    url = "http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=#{ currentID }"
    res = HTTParty.get(url)
    pRes = res.parsed_response["#{ currentID }"]

    # Check For Eligibility

    # Get Eligibility Info
    begin
      type = pRes["data"]["type"] == 'game' ? true : false
      success = pRes["success"]
      paid = pRes["data"].has_key? "price_overview"

      if type && success && paid
        name = pRes["data"]["name"]
        appid = currentID
        img = pRes["data"]["header_image"]
        description = pRes["data"]["detailed_description"]
        dev = pRes["data"]["developers"][0]
        publisher = pRes["data"]["publishers"][0]

        Mongolize(name, appid, img, description, dev, publisher)
      elsif !type
        puts "Not a Game"
      elsif !success
        puts "API call Failed"
      elsif !paid
        puts "Free Game"
      end
    rescue NoMethodError
      puts "ERROR: 404: JSON Object does not Exist"
    end

    # Iterator
    currentID += 10
  end
end
```

Comment: Methods defined in one file are *not* scoped to that file. Otherwise, it would be impossible to ever break up an application into multiple files. The whole concept of the standard library and the RubyGems ecosystem could not exist, if that were true, since the whole *point* of the standard library and gems is to use methods defined in different files.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly which method is called on which object in which line. With that information, you should be able to find the error yourself. Without that information, there is nothing we can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `res.parsed_response` is `nil` and `[]` is being called on `nil`.

Parsed_response is `nil` for the id 0, if you change it to 1 it runs but returns 404 errors.

You can use `p res` to see the `HTTParty` object or install pry and use `require 'pry'; binding.pry` just after the response is returned.

Comment: But how do I rectify this (i.e. parse the response and not have it be nil)?

Comment: You can't, it is nil. You could do something like add `next unless res.parsed_response` which will skip ids that return an object with a nil parsed response.